# Não é possível criar uma instância do controle ActiveX porque o thread atual não está em um STA

Tags: c#, .net, thread

Estou tentando acessar um site pelo WebBrowser e hoje de manhã, subitamente, apareceu o seguinte erro

> Não é possível criar uma instância do controle ActiveX '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' porque o thread atual não está em um STA (single-threaded apartment).

Não estou conseguindo resolver, pois nunca tinha entrado em contato com esse tipo de erro.

Segue uma parte do código:

```
string sSite = "http://online.sefaz.am.gov.br/diselada/consultadi.asp";
Uri sUri = new Uri(sSite);

WebBrowser webSiscomex = new WebBrowser();
webSiscomex.AllowNavigation = true;
webSiscomex.Navigate(sSite);
webSiscomex.Width = 700;
webSiscomex.Height = 500;
webSiscomex.Visible = true;
webSiscomex.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
webSiscomex.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
webSiscomex.Show();
```

Comment: Será que esta pergunta te ajuda?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor? Não entendi, sua pergunta!

Comment: Nossa, me desculpe rs... esqueci de colocar o link! Da uma olhada nesse link e vê se te ajuda! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418466/single-threaded-apartment-cannot-instantiate-activex-control

Comment: Ah! Ta vem! Obrigada!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aplicações Windows possuem duas formas de lidar com threads: [*Single Thread Apartment*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms680112(v=vs.85).aspx) e [*Multithread Apartment*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms693421(v=vs.85).aspx). Cada modelo tem uma abordagem sobre como objetos podem ser acessados.

As diferenças entre ambos os modelos são um estudo bem extenso. Por hora você precisa saber que os controles visuais de aplicações Windows em geral só conseguem trabalhar no modelo *Single Thread Apartment* (STA), enquanto controles que lidam com threads (i.e.: background worker) em geral criam threads no modelo *Multithread apartment (MA)*.

Eu acho que você instancia o *WebBrowser* em uma thread separada da thread principal do formulário, certo? A solução é forçar a thread onde você instancia o *WebBrowser* a utilizar o modelo STA, assim:

```
Thread t = new Thread(foo); // onde foo é o método que a Thread t irá executar
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```

Baseei o suposto acima [nesta resposta no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1418471/2263584).

Comment: Compreendi e fiz essa implementação aqui. E deu super certo! Não sabia disso. Muito obrigada pela ajuda!